# Do I need to restart SUSE when upgrade glibc?

Tags: linux, database, sles, glibc

I plan to upgrade glibc version (HAVE to install by rpm command) on 30 SUSE machines, all the machine are using for running test on Jenkins. Could someone tell me the reboot is needed in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should reboot. Glibc provides the C library used by virtually every program on the system; all must be restarted in order to use the newly installed version.